# Help with understanding Eritrea factions

Tags: eritrea

Around the world there has been a few events where Eritrea Culture days have been attacked.

This article has some info, but I am unsure how biased it is.

https://tesfanews.net/international-campaign-of-violence-against-eritrean-festivals/

I noticed it because of the events in Copenhagen where a lot got arrested.

Based on the flags the attackers had (blue with green wreath) I assume they must be pro some kind of Eritrean Liberation Front.

But, I am more interested in the culture days that are being held. Is there any evidence that they are pro the current government? E.g. do they send funds to people that support the current goventment or endorse it in any way? Do they belong to a faction that has a name?

Comment: This question is a little scrambled and stream of consciousness. And, when you say "pro the current government", do you mean the government and political system of Eritrea or the government and political system of Denmark?

Comment: How about something like "Can someone explain what's behind the coordinated violence at Eritrean diaspora events such as in Copenhagen.  And [Israel](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-66700307)?  Who is fighting against whom?"

Comment: The question is about if the Culture Festivals around the world are coordinated by a group that support the current government in Eritrea. I am fairly certain I am correct that the attacks are coordinated by ELF

Comment: @ThomasKoelle That is already most of an answer, you identified two factions that are fighting each other. Please add a source (wikipedia probably suffices) and write it up as an answer.

Comment: @quarague I can't write it as an answer. Those beeing attacked seems peaceful, so it could just be people the does not support the governement but just wants to have a festival showing the food etc.

Comment: The ELF stopped existing as such 40 years ago, according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The ELF stopped existing as such 40 years ago, according to Wikipedia.

[OTOH](https://apnews.com/article/eritrea-diaspora-violence-canada-germany-sweden-e76577e0928c071a4010268c02fd6ef9):

> Beyene Gerezgiher, a member of the Eritrean community in Europe who leads an organization that seeks regime change in Eritrea, told The Associated Press that a separate group called the **Brigade Nhamedu** was set up last year to counter what it calls the government’s hate speech and war propaganda. The word “Nhamedu” means being ready to fight and sacrifice.
>
> A U.S.-based organizer of the Brigade Nhamedu, Henok Tekle, described the group as “mass discontent and anger against the regime” led by young Eritreans who he said had experienced the injustices of Eritrea’s one-party state.
>
> The group doesn’t advocate violence, said Henok, the executive director of a satellite television station aimed at countering what it calls government propaganda. But he acknowledged that protests at festivals often turn into violence because of different factions are present.
>
> [...]
>
> Some Eritreans and state-backed media have blamed attacks in Stockholm, Toronto and the German town of Giessen in part on ethnic Tigrayans from northern Ethiopia. That’s where Eritrean forces joined Ethiopia’s military in fighting a two-year war against Tigray forces until a peace deal was made in November. Eritrean forces were accused of some of the worst atrocities, including gang rapes.
>
> Kassa Hailemariam, a U.S.-based advocate for many Tigrayans, told the AP “it is ridiculous to blame Tigrayans for the global Eritrean movement against the age-long dictator in Asmara,” Eritrea’s capital. “We are not part of this movement!”

So yeah, it's not terribly clear who the attackers were. No organized group seems to want to claim responsibility.

Anyhow, there [appear](https://archive.is/MNR1s#selection-1459.0-1467.344) to be multiple such opposition groups

> Semhar Ghebreslassie, a Sweden-based member of global Eritrean activist group **Yiakl**, said activists in Sweden had written letters to the authorities urging them not to allow the festival, but had been ignored.
>
> “These programmes are to promote the brutal dictatorship, to glorify war and whitewash the name of the dictator himself,” she said. “They try to portray Eritrea as a heaven on Earth, that it’s in good hands and that the west is evil. This is all done to brainwash and keep people under control, especially kids born and raised in the diaspora.”

How closely they coordinate is hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for info. I am unsure if you covered the last paragraph that I am curious about though.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle: at least those opposition groups claim the festivals glorify Afwerki, whom they regard as no better than Putin. And yeas, they also claim the festivals serve as fundraisers for the regime https://martinplaut.com/2023/08/29/disguised-as-cultural-festivals-eritrean-government-spreads-war-propaganda-with-kalashnikovs-and-calls-for-genocide/

Comment: Yet another example how troubles just start for a country when it attains independence...